# Android replace fragment inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle, android-support-library

I have 2 fragments inside parent fragment. In `OnCreateView()` of parent fragment I try to show these fragments via `replace(int, Fragment)`. As I understand, `FragmentTransaction#commit()` is being called asynchronously.

So, if user quickly presses back button -- the system will destroy parent fragment (it calls `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroyView()`, `onDestroy()`) and asynchronous replacing task will fail -- parent view is destroyed and system throws "**IllegalArgumentException**: No view found for fragment MyFragment". I use support library.

So, how can I manage this case?
I'll be highly appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. For nested fragments `getChildFragmentManager()` should be used instead of `getFragmentManager()`. `ChildFragmentManager` appears to track a lifecycle of parent fragment and cancel scheduled commits if parent fragment is going to be destroyed.